# Angular Directive Transclusion Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angularjs-1.5

I am creating a custom directive as follows:

```
<directive-a attribute-a="customData" attribute-b="customKey">
   <!--Transcluded Content-->
</directive-a>
```

The scenario is as follows:

1. The `directive-a` is within the scope of a `controllerA`.
2. The directive receives the customData(Array of Objects) from `controllerA` and **groups** the data in customData based on a particular key provided(customKey)
3. It inserts an `ng-repeat` dynamically using javascript and transcludes the Transcluded-Content within the `ng-repeat` using the transcludeFunction and then finally compiles the parent of `ng-repeat` to display the list.

The Transcluded-Content would act as a template(passed by the user) in which the data would be passed by the `directive-a`.

The problem being faced is that, when the Transcluded-Content is static, it works properly, but when the Transcluded-Content is a **custom-user created directive**, then an angular reports the following error

> Cannot read property 'X' of undefined.

The reason of this error(*I think*) is that angular looks for the data of the user passed custom directive in the `scope of controllerA` and is unable to find it thereby causing the error.

How do I go about this to solve the my issue?

Angular Version : 1.5.8

[JSFiddle Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/manish_demblani/qm60a393/)

Comment: Did you try to just use a template with `<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-translude></div>`?

Comment: Yes have. tried that, but that does not work due to the transclusion policy of angularJS. In this case although it would transcluded the content, but the parent scope of the tranaclude content would be that of controllerA and not directive-a

Comment: You can take a look at the source code for ng-table it use $data from directive like this `<table ng-table="vm.tableParams"><tr ng-repeat="user in $data">...</tr></table>`

Comment: A part solution that worked, was that rather than placing the content inside ng-repeat, it would be better if I add the transcluded content manually using javascriipt logic.